# How can i access related data and convert foreign keys into objects for displaying their properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have

```
class User {
...
...
ICollection<Transaction> transactionsUserMade;
}
```

and

```
class Transaction {
int ID;
int userThatSentMoneyID;
int userToWhomHeSentMoneyID;
}
```

I'm trying to make profile page where user can see all transactions he made and to whom. I managed to relate users and transaction but I'm getting integer values, as i should by using

```
await _context.Users
    .Include(u => u.transactionsUserMade)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.ID == userId);
```

How can i turn those ID's to actual objects of Users so i could get their usernames and display them on Razor Page.

Comment: You are *getting integer values*, that doesn't make sense. The query you show will give you a `User` object. How are you using it?

Comment: Yes it does. But them i want to loop through his transactions. And by looping i can get only `userToWhomHeSentMoneyID` property for every transaction. I want to use that ID to find user and use its name for display. @DavidG

Comment: Well does your `User` and `Transaction` model have to be that way and you can't change them? I saw you're using `Include()`. I think the relationship between `User` and `Transaction` is not setup correctly. You could have easily achieved what you want by using navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution. I tweaked Transaction class by adding `User userThatRecievedMoney` property. And after getting transactions from specific user i manually set that property.

```
foreach(var transaction in _user.transactionsUserMade)
{
    transaction.userThatRecievedMoney = _context.Users
       .Where(u => u.ID == transaction.userToWhomHeSentMoneyID).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Navigation Property` to help you with that as long as you can modify those entity models `User` and `Transaction`.

```
public class UserEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public List<TransactionEntity> TransactionsAsSender { get; set; }
    public List<TransactionEntity> TransactionsAsRecipient { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }

    // Foreign key to UserEntity
    public int SenderId { get; set; }
    public UserEntity Sender { get; set; }

    // Foreign key to UserEntity
    public int RecipientId { get; set; }
    public UserEntity Recipient { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to setup their relationships.

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<UserEntity>(b => {
            b.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            b.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();
            b.Property(x => x.Email).IsRequired();

            b.ToTable("User");
        });

        builder.Entity<TransactionEntity>(b => {
           b.HasKey(x => x.Id);
           b.Property(x => x.Amount).IsRequired();

           // Configure relationships
           b.HasOne(x => x.Sender)
               .WithMany(u => u.TransactionsAsSender)
               .HasForeignKey(x => x.SenderId);

           b.HasOne(x => x.Recipient)
               .WithMany(u => u.TransactionsAsRecipient)
               .HasForeignKey(x => x.RecipientId);

           b.ToTable("Transaction");
        });
    }

    public DbSet<UserEntity> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TransactionEntity> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

After their relationships are setup, you can easily query the related data via navigation properties.

For example, let's say you have view model called `UserProfileViewModel` and `UserProfileTransactionViewModel` to contain the information it needs for display purpose.

```
public class UserProfileViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<UserProfileTransactionViewModel> TransactionsAsSender { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserProfileTransactionViewModel> TransactionsAsRecipient { get; set }
}

public class UserProfileTransactionViewModel
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string Sender { get; set; }
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller,

```
var user = _dbContext.Users
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(x => x.TransactionsAsSender)
    .Include(x => x.TransactionsAsRecipient)
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId);

if (user == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}

var vm = new UserProfileViewModel
{
    UserId = user.Id,
    UserName = user.Name,
    UserEmail = user.Email,
    TransactionsAsSender = user.TransactionsAsSender
        .Select(x => new UserProfileTransactionViewModel
        {
            TransactionId = x.Id,
            Sender = x.Sender.Name,
            Recipient = x.Recipient.Name,
            Amount = x.Amount.ToString("c")
        }),
    TransactionsAsRecipient = user.TransactionsAsRecipient
         .Select(x => new UserProfileTransactionViewModel
        {
            TransactionId = x.Id,
            Sender = x.Sender.Name,
            Recipient = x.Recipient.Name,
            Amount = x.Amount.ToString("c")
        })      
};

return View(vm);
```

You could even have just a list of all transactions off `UserProfileViewModel`. You can combine `TransactionsAsSender` and `TransactionsAsRecipient` from `UserEntity` to fill the list.

#### Disclaim:

I wrote everything by hand and with my imagination :p